# C++ library for calculating the matrix exponential

Tags: c++, matrix, linear-algebra

Any recommendations for libraries to implement calculation of the matrix exponential?

Comment: `e**A` are typically done using Taylor expansion

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you need it for? I'd imagine for a system of ODEs (x' = A*x), integrating the ODEs is usually a better plan.

Comment: stability analysis of a partition - http://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.1770

Answer (score 1):

[Expokit](http://www.maths.uq.edu.au/expokit/) is written in fortran, but can be embedded in C++.  It works great and includes an optimized algorithm for sparse matrices.